# Keep only last row for each group and month-year

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks similar to this:

```
   ID      Date       Day_Val       Title
------------------------------------------
  AAA   2021-06-05    14              A
  AAA   2021-06-12    11              B
  AAA   2021-06-12    11              C
  AAA   2021-06-12    11              D
  AAA   2021-06-21    15              E
  AAA   2021-06-22    15              F
  AAA   2021-06-22    15              G
  BBB   2021-06-06    33              H
  BBB   2021-06-18    35              I
  BBB   2021-06-27    55              J
  BBB   2021-06-27    55              K
  BBB   2021-06-27    55              L
  BBB   2021-06-27    55              M
  AAA   2021-07-08    6               N
  AAA   2021-07-08    6               O
  AAA   2021-07-12    8               P
  AAA   2021-07-12    8               Q
```

(Note too that the `Date` column are `String` types)

What I would like to do is keep only one row for the final month-year combination for each group - if other columns have several rows, then they are okay to keep. So for example, my final output should look like this:

```
   ID      Date       Day_Val       Title
------------------------------------------
  AAA   2021-06-05    14              A
  AAA   2021-06-12    11              B
  AAA   2021-06-12    11              C
  AAA   2021-06-12    11              D
  AAA   2021-06-21    15              E
  AAA   2021-06-22    15              G
  BBB   2021-06-06    33              H
  BBB   2021-06-18    35              I
  BBB   2021-06-27    55              M
  AAA   2021-07-08    6               N
  AAA   2021-07-08    6               O
  AAA   2021-07-12    8               Q
```

Basically, I want to keep duplicate rows as long as they are not the last duplicate row for each group and month-year combination

Unfortunately, I'm having quite a bit of difficulty with it, so if anyone could help I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Is `Day_Val` the same for all identical days within one `ID` group (looks like it)? I.e. could there be a row `AAA   2021-06-12    10` in addition to the currently present rows?

Answer (score 0):

In that case try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_excel("E:/stackOverFlow/date_data.xlsx")
df_col=df.columns


df['ID'] = df["ID"].astype(str) 
df['Date'] = df["Date"].astype(str) 


m1 = df.duplicated(['ID','Date'], keep="last") # is it the last row per group?
m2 = ~df.duplicated(['ID','Date'], keep=False) # is it not duplicated?
result_df = df[m1|m2]
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately this method removes all duplicates - in my dataframe, I only wish to remove duplicates of the last row for each group and month-year combination, such that if there are duplicates of elsewhere in the group and in the month year it's okay (similar to how it's given in the dataframe above)

Comment: updated. Just check if it is working. kindly please upvote my answer if its working

Comment: Unfortunately, the update still does not work :( I will continue trying to figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption that (1) `Day_Val` is only determined by the `ID` and `Date`, and (2) `Date` is sorted within each `ID` group (ascending), you could try the following:

```py
month = df["Date"].str.rsplit("-", n=1).str[0]
last = df["Date"] == df.groupby(["ID", month])["Date"].transform("last")
m = ~df[last].duplicated(subset=["ID", "Date"], keep="last")
res = df[m.reindex(df.index, fill_value=True)]
```

- First extract the months from the `Date` strings (you also could do that by casting the `Date` column to datetimes and then use `.dt` methods).
- Then identify the last dates by grouping over `Date` and `month` and picking the last `Date` (`.transform` keeps the original shape) and compare the result with the original `Date` column.
- Then use `.duplicated` on `df` for the `ID` and `Date` columns, but restricted to the rows that belong to a `last` group. The `keep="last"` sets `False` on that row and `True` on all others. So by negating the result (`~`) you'll have a mask `m` for only the last rows.
- Finally fill `m` in all other places (i.e. indices in the original `df`) to `True`, because you want to keep them too, and extract the rows based on that.

Result for the sample is:

```
     ID        Date  Day_Val Title
0   AAA  2021-06-05       14     A
1   AAA  2021-06-12       11     B
2   AAA  2021-06-12       11     C
3   AAA  2021-06-12       11     D
4   AAA  2021-06-21       15     E
6   AAA  2021-06-22       15     G
7   BBB  2021-06-06       33     H
8   BBB  2021-06-18       35     I
12  BBB  2021-06-27       55     M
13  AAA  2021-07-08        6     N
14  AAA  2021-07-08        6     O
16  AAA  2021-07-12        8     Q
```